# Overloading with referenced-passed pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, operator-overloading

I'm trying to create a bookstore program that reads inputs from user until `EOF`. In order to do that, I overloaded the `istream >> operator` among other things.

```
class CSales {
public:
    //constructors 

    friend ostream & operator << ( ostream &os, const CSales &x ) const;
    friend istream & operator >> ( istream &is, const CSales &x );

    //m_vars
};
istream & operator >> ( istream &is, const CSales &x ) {
    /* following line prints error:
     * no match for 'operator>>' */
    if ( is >> x.m_isbn >> x.m_price >> x.m_count ) {
        x.m_revenue = x.m_count*x.m_price; //assignment of member is read-only object
    }

    return is;
}

int main() {
    vector<CSales*> dbs1;
    CSales *candidate = new CSales();

    while ( cin >> *candidate ) {
        //sorted by isbn
        auto iter = lower_bound(dbs1.begin(), dbs1.end(), candidate, cmp_isbn);
        //operations 

    return 0;
}
```

1. I have a suspicion that the overload is not working because I'm trying to pass a pointer using reference. Am I correct in that assumption?
2. The way I understood it, `const CSales x` would be incorrect since I would be changing the pointer, not the object I'm pointing to. So that possibly leaves me with either `const CSales &*x` or `const CSales *&x`. What's the difference between those two?
3. I don't know why the `x.m_revenue` line is not working, why is it read-only if I don't have the operator as `const`?

[FULL CODE](https://pastebin.com/gYvGVDYb).

EDIT: I'm using a vector of pointers to objects because that should make sorting more efficient (only moving pointers, not the object itself).

Comment: Note that while the input and output operators are declared in the scope of the `CSales` class, they are *not* member functions. Therefore you can not have the `const` specifier on the output operator. That will give you build errors.

Comment: As for your errors, your input operator *modifies* the object `x`. I.e. it can not be `const`.

Comment: I understand now that my `ostream` shouldn't have `const` but I don't have `const` in `istream`.

Comment: Regarding your "efficiency" reason for using pointers. It is often a red herring, and premature optimizations are always bad. Design and code first of all for *simplicity*, for *readability*, for *maintainability*. Then test it, measure it, benchmark it. And if there are situations where the performance seems to be lacking, you measure and profile to find the bottlenecks, and fix only those. With plenty of comments about *why* the code is what it is, as optimizations tend to lead to code that hard to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
istream & operator >> ( istream &is, const CSales &x ) {
//                                   ^^^^^
```

This tells the compiler that `x` is *constant*, that you will not modify `x`. But as it's an input operator it definitely modifies `x` or it would not make much sense.

The error message "assignment of member of ***read-only*** object" should have been a very clear hint about the issue.

Your suspicion of problems with pointers is a red herring (but I still would recommend you look into a way to *not* use pointers, pointers in modern C++ is often not needed beyond polymorphism).

---

And to clarify my first comment:

```
class CSales {
public:
    ...
    friend ostream & operator << ( ostream &os, const CSales &x ) const;
    //                                                            ^^^^^
    ...
};
```

The `operator<<` function is a *non-member* function, so adding the `const` qualifier should lead to build-errors. Only member functions can be `const` qualified.

Comment: I missed the argument, now it makes sense. Thank you. Just curious, would you be kind enough to address my question 2 in a hypothetical scenario?

Comment: @HichigayaHachiman I'm not really sure what you mean by that, but e.g. `CSales&*x` means that `x` is a pointer to a reference, which doesn't make sense and should not work. `CSales*& x` is a reference to a pointer which makes sense if you want to modify the pointer.